# Block spam mail from forwarded domain

Tags: postfix

I get a lot of spam mail at my Gmail account. I also get a lot of important mail at my Gmail account.

The spam email is coming from a handful of domains.

I have Gmail forwarding all email to my postfix server with MX records correctly setup.

I have postfix pcre setup.

Looking for some command line magic to automatically delete forwarded mail originally from domain X (not gmail.com) on my postfix server.

Answer (score 0):

I think I was able to solve it with body_checks

```
# /etc/postfix/body_checks
/domainx/ DISCARD
```

The second file I edited was:

```
# /etc/postfix/main.cf
body_checks = pcre:/etc/postfix/body_checks
```

Followed by:

```
sudo systemctl restart postfix
```